# SpriteKit Bouncing Object

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

I have an object that I am trying to have bounce on a horizontal ground that is elevated from a certain distance about the bottom of the screen. How do I go about having an object bounce at a steady rate up and down along this ground? I have:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -5.0);
object.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0;
object.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0;
```

and then within the contact method, whenever my bouncing object falls due to gravity and collides with my ground, I apply an impulse:

```
[object.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0.0, 10.0)];
```

My issue is this approach is sporadic. The effects of gravity take time to increase the acceleration in each time interval. The object starts out bouncing super high and over time it doesn't even bounce anymore. Does anyone have a better approach to fluidly bounce my object up and down without losing energy?

Comment: energy loss due to friction by default its value is 0.2 change it to 0.0 solve your problem

Comment: also check the allowrotation property its need to be false

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)floor
{
    SKSpriteNode *floor = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"floor"];
    floor.position = yourPosition;
    floor.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:floor.frame];
    floor.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
}

-(void)ball
{
    SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];
    ball.position = yourPosition;
    ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];
    ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.5;
}
```